# Can 'can not' be used for prohibition?

Tags: vocabulary, negation

> You **can’t** do that sort of thing. (Random House Unabridged)
>   You **can't** leave until you finish washing the dishes. ([Webster’s Learner’s](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/can))

When ‘*can*’ is used for prohibition, does it have to stuck with *not*, that is, do *cannot* or *can’t* have to be used; not permitting '*can not*'? I thought that ‘*you **can not** do that sort of thing*’ has equal meaning of the dictionary's example, but I don’t find any examples of ‘*can not*’. Can’t we use ‘*can not*’, when we do not give permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking around for differences between *can not* and *cannot*, [dailywritingtips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/cannot-or-can-not/) has a nice list of sources that tell you to use *cannot*:

OED says:

> [cannot is] the ordinary modern way of writing can not.

[askoxford](http://www.askoxford.com/asktheexperts/faq/aboutspelling/cannot?view=uk) says:

> Both cannot and can not are acceptable spellings, but the first is much more usual. You would use can not when the ‘not’ forms part of another construction such as ‘not only.’

[Washington State University](http://www.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/cannot.html) says on their site:

> These two spellings [cannot/can not] are largely interchangeable, but by far the most common is “cannot” and you should probably use it except when you want to be emphatic: “No, you can not wash the dog in the Maytag.”

So it doesn't seem to have to do with the prohibitive use of *cannot*, but the preference seems quite universal.

Answer (score 1):

Orthographically speaking, **cannot** is the preferred form. In fact if I write *can not*, my computer automatically changes it to *cannot*. However, I feel there's a place for *can not*, namely when you want to emphasize the word *not*:

> You can't talk to her like that. (=denying permission or statement of fact)
>
> You cannot talk to her like that. (=same as above, somewhat more authoritative)
>
> You can *not* talk to her like that! (=separated in order to emphasize *not* - categorical denial of permission)

Sometimes this emphasis is achieved by italicizing *cannot*. My personal recommendation is to stick with **can't** and **cannot**, however if you use **can *not*** for effect, use italics to make this clear.

This [article](http://www.write.com/writing-resources-articles/general-writing/word-choice/cannot-versus-can-not/) might help.